# modify class in stylesheet in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in asp.net and c#.

I have a css stylesheet named STYLE.css in my application,and i have a some classes in that stylesheet.I want to change the style in that classes in my codebehind.How to do that.Give ur suggessions.

**Style.CSS**:

```
 .someclass
  {
   //some attributes

  }
```

I Want to change the attributes of **someclass** Class in codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to keep control over styling in the css file. so create 2 classes in the css and change the class that the control uses in the code behind.

This means that you can keep styling seperate from function, and will make the maintenance of the code easier. Because when you decide you want a slightly different shade of color you only need to change a css entry rather than recompile your application/project.